# Reading the file names from standard input using scanf() c

Tags: c, scanf

How do I make a program where the user can type the file names (input and output files) to which they want to read and write to, on standard input using scanf?
e.g when they run the program ./start filename1 filename2
(in C).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is no coding service or teaching site.

Comment: `./start filename1 filename2` is not using the standard input using `scanf`.

Answer (score 0):

If they run the program this way:

```
./start filename1 filename2
```

The input and output filenames are passed to the `main` function in the `argv` array.  No need and indeed no way to use `scanf` to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by learning how to open a text file and how write text.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

After if you know that, you can take argument in the main function (argc, argv), that will give you information of the parameters entered in the command line

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
     //arc : how many value are in the command line
     //argv : array of string, string from each parameter in the command line
     //argc = 3
     //argv = {"./start", "filename1", "filename2"}
     return 0;
}
```

After you can use scanf to get value from the user. And after each scanf you can write in the file. Don't forget to close the file at the end.